# Wordpress Кастомный тип постов, кастомные поля, ревизии

Tags: php, wordpress

есть проблема
мне нужно чтобы в вордпресс записывать кастомные поля в ревизию
есть код

```
function cfr_filter_meta($meta) {
    $meta_filtered = [];
    foreach ($meta as $key => $value) {
        if ($key{0} != "_")
            $meta_filtered[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $meta_filtered;
}
function cfr_get_meta($post_id) {
    $meta = get_metadata("post", $post_id);
    $meta = cfr_filter_meta($meta);
    return $meta;
}
function cfr_insert_meta($post_id, $meta) {
    foreach ($meta as $meta_key => $meta_value) {
        if (is_array($meta_value))
            foreach ($meta_value as $single_meta_value)
                add_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key, $single_meta_value);
        else
            add_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
    }
}
function cfr_delete_meta($post_id) {
    $meta = cfr_get_meta($post_id);
    foreach ($meta as $meta_key => $meta_value) {
        delete_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key);
    }
}
function cfr_field($value, $field, $revision) {
    $revision_id = $revision->ID;
    $meta = cfr_get_meta($revision_id);
    $return = "";
    foreach ($meta as $meta_key => $meta_value) {
        $return .= $meta_key . ": " . join(", ", $meta_value) . "\n";
    }
    return $return;
}
function cfr_fields($fields)
{
    $fields["custom_fields"] = "Custom Fields";
    return $fields;
}
function cfr_restore_revision($post_id, $revision_id) {
    $meta = cfr_get_meta($revision_id);
    cfr_delete_meta($post_id);
    cfr_insert_meta($post_id, $meta);
    $revisions = wp_get_post_revisions($post_id);
    if (count($revisions) > 0) {
        $last_revision = current($revisions);
        cfr_delete_meta($last_revision->ID);
        cfr_insert_meta($last_revision->ID, $meta);
    }
}
function cfr_save_post($post_id, $post) {
    if ($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
        $meta = cfr_get_meta(get_post($parent_id)->ID);
        if ($meta === false)
            return;
        cfr_insert_meta($post_id, $meta);
    }
}
function cfr_post_has_changed($post_has_changed, $last_revision, $post) {
    if (!$post_has_changed)
    {
        $meta = cfr_get_meta(get_post($last_revision)->ID);
        $meta_new = cfr_get_meta($post->ID);
        if ($meta === $meta_new)
            return $post_has_changed;
        return true;
    }
    return $post->ID;
}
add_action('save_post', 'cfr_save_post', 10, 2);
add_action('wp_restore_post_revision', 'cfr_restore_revision', 10, 2);
add_filter('wp_save_post_revision_post_has_changed', 'cfr_post_has_changed', 10, 3);
add_filter('_wp_post_revision_fields', 'cfr_fields', 10, 1);
add_filter("_wp_post_revision_field_custom_fields", "cfr_field", 10, 3);
```

Он отлично работает на обычных постах а вот в кастомном типе постов он все записывает но страница уходит в **Сайт пока не может обработать этот запрос.**
Помогите разобратся в чем проблема

Comment: Без структуры таблиц и описания связей вопрос не имеет смысла. Равно как не имеет смысла перемешивание SQL-кода и PHP-переменных.

Comment: а зачем структура таблиц если я все условия указал?
по поводу перемешивания чёт не совсем понял поясни

Comment: Используйте JOIN, там хоть сколько можно за раз вызвать таблиц

Comment: Помогите исправить)))